# Recuva-like software for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery, gui

Recuva is a Windows application used to undelete files [Piriform Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

It has a nice GUI and is very dependable.

Is there anything similar for Ubuntu?